# C++ combination of stod and stoi?

Tags: c++11

Is there a combination of stod and stoi?
So that I could have a string s = "0.1 1 2.3 3 4.4"
and stod_stoi_combined(s) would extract me doubles and ints depending on what the input is?

Comment: How about implementing it yourself? Seems straightforward. Let me know if you need some hints.

Comment: Just use `stod` for every case and use `std::modf` to find out of it's integral or not.

Comment: This comment should be the answer, if would prefer it as complement to the already given answer. It's exactly what I wanted. Didn't hear about modf but seems really handy. Oh and it's not std::modf it's just modf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such combination in the standard library.

There can be no such combination, because the return type of a function cannot depend on the value of the parameter. The return type is always the same, not sometimes int and other times double.

You could possibly write a function that returns `std::variant<int, double>`. Note that `std::variant` isn't part of the standard library until the upcoming C++17, so if you cannot wait, you'll have to use a third party alternative.